# /var keeps filling up

Tags: partitioning, 22.04, cleanup

I am on Ubuntu 22.04. My /dev/sda2 partition keeps running out of space. I delete files here and there as temporary fixes. I have deleted journal files and did auto-remove as well, but now these options aren't enough either. I still can't figure out what is causing /var to fill up.

```
 df -Th | grep '^/dev'
```

gives

```
/dev/sda2      ext4    23G   21G  764M  97% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat   146M  104M   43M  72% /boot/efi
/dev/sda4      ext4   863G   31G  789G   4% /home
```

and running

```
lsblk /dev/sda
```

gives

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  23.3G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host- 
hunspell
│                                /
├─sda3   8:3    0  30.5G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda4   8:4    0 877.7G  0 part /home
```

'/dev/sda2' is the one running out of space. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 9 GB of `/var` is normal. The reason it is filling up, is probably that you have allocated a very small sized partition for `/var`, which was wrong at the first place. You should increase the size of the `/var` partition. Even completely deleting the separate partition for `/var` and consolidating it into the root partition, may be something advisable.

Comment: @FedKad actually the partition is 23 GB, so something else is the problem in this case? I haven't found a way to list the sizes of files by partition. Any leads on that? Thanks!

Comment: You question lacks extra information. At least the output of `df -Th | grep '^/dev'` and `lsblk /dev/sda` should be included in your question. Please [edit] your question to add extra info.

Comment: @FedKad thanks, i have added the suggested information

Comment: Check logfile sizes in /var/log/ . If any are discovered, they are merely a symptom. Read the logfile to determine the actual cause that must be fixed.

Comment: `sudo apt install ncdu` then `sudo ncdu /var` and this will reveal chunky files to investigate.